# Apache Beam Hello World Example ContextualVersionConflict

Tags: python-2.7, apache-beam, google-colaboratory

my goal is to run the wordcount [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount_minimal.py) in a Colab Notebook to better understand the Apache Beam approach.

I get several version mismatch errors though when running things out of the box:
`ContextualVersionConflict: (pytz 2018.5 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pytz<=2018.4,>=2018.3'), set(['apache-beam']))`

I tried downgrading pytz to version 2018.4 but to no avail.

I also tried downgrading google-cloud-core, oauth2 but that introduces new version incompatibilities.

Any idea how to resolve the issues?

My notbook can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zGyEBLR6ug3TBKv-2B6MPBzWAfgcilVb)